# How to change what an ES6 arrow function's 'this' points to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, this, ecmascript-6

In the `traverse` npm package there's this example

```
var obj = [ 5, 6, -3, [ 7, 8, -2, 1 ], { f : 10, g : -13 } ];

traverse(obj).forEach(function (x) {
    if (x < 0) this.update(x + 128);
});
```

Inside the callback function you can call `this.update`. I know in these kinds of cases you should use the regular (not ES6 arrow) style of  function definitions like shown above.

But out of curiosity, how would you make that code work with ES6 arrow function syntax? If I try as follows I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined` because of course `this` is not the same as above.

```
traverse(obj).forEach((x) => {
    if (x < 0) this.update(x + 128);
});
```

I tried to change `this` by using `bind` but wasn't successful. How do you change `this` in ES6 arrow functions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How do you change `this` in ES6 arrow functions?

You can't, that's the whole point of using arrow functions (besides concise syntax). If you need to control `this`, don't use an arrow function.

Answer (score 4):

Arrow functions in [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) have [lexical this](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis). This means you can always tell their `this`-value by asking the question "What was the value of `this` when the function was defined?" They are immune to the `this`-altering effects of call, apply, bind, and method invocation.

Let's take a look at the intended effect by compiling ES6 to ES5 with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

ES6:

```
let foo = {
  bar() {
    return [
      () => this,
      function() { 
        return this 
      }
    ]
  },
  baz: () => this
}

let fns = foo.bar()
fns.push(...fns.map((fn, i) => fn.bind({i})))
fns.map(fn => fn()).forEach(thisVal => {
  console.log(thisVal)
  console.log('-------')
})
console.log(foo.baz())
```

Compiled to ES5:

```
'use strict';

function _toConsumableArray(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { for (var i = 0, arr2 = Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; } else { return Array.from(arr); } }

var foo = {
  bar: function bar() {
    var _this = this;

    return [function () {
      return _this;
    }, function () {
      return this;
    }];
  },

  baz: function baz() {
    return undefined;
  }
};

var fns = foo.bar();
fns.push.apply(fns, _toConsumableArray(fns.map(function (fn, i) {
  return fn.bind({ i: i });
})));
fns.map(function (fn) {
  return fn();
}).forEach(function (thisVal) {
  console.log(thisVal);
  console.log('-------');
});
console.log(foo.baz());
```

Check out what happened inside `foo.bar`. There was an inserted line:

```
var _this = this;
```

The arrow function's body was changed so that it returned `_this` from its lexical outer scope. Therefore, binding the value of `this` is not supposed to have any effect. By "freezing" the value of "this" just before the function definition, we have prevented the ability to change the function's behavior through binding, using call/apply, or calling the function as a method.

Notice how `baz`'s this value was simply replaced with `undefined`. That's because if we ask the question "What was the value of `this` when the function was defined?", we obviously must answer either `undefined` or some global object context, like Node's `global` or the browser's `window`. By asking this question, you can easily deduce the value of `this` inside arrow functions, and that is a big part of their inherent value.

The output is therefore:

```
{ bar: [Function: bar], baz: [Function: baz] }
-------
undefined
-------
{ bar: [Function: bar], baz: [Function: baz] }
-------
{ i: 1 }
-------
undefined
```

The first and third outputs correspond to the arrow function defined within `bar()`. Notice how they automatically have a `this`-value that points to the object referred to by `foo` because they were created with the `foo.bar()` call. Useful right? Only the behavior of the non-arrow function could be changed by binding. Before binding, it's `this`-value was `undefined`, a common cause of many JS bugs and redundant bindings when passing around functions. Arrow functions take away a lot of that hassle.