# Why this code return always undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I start learning ES6 & wrote this code :

```js
let dog = {
      s:'Woff',
      talk:()=>{console.log(this.s)}
    };
    dog.talk();
    let x = dog.talk;
    x();
    x.bind(dog)();
```

why it always returns undefined instead 'Woff' ? I think just 1 line returning undefined but we have 3 undefined .

Comment: console.log returns undefined.

Comment: 1. You don't have any `return` statements here, and 2. you `console.log(console.log(...))`

Comment: @JaredSmith Just checked the docs, and since he has `{}` (block body) he needs a return as far as I can tell: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: I think everyone is reading too much into the use of the word "returns" here… http://stackoverflow.com/q/33723263/476 was a perfectly good duplicate.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue under *FunctionBody*: `var func = (x, y) => { return x + y; }; // with block body, explicit "return" needed`

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I never said that you needed to have a return statement, but that to *return a value*, which I think the question implies, you *do* because of that rule.

Comment: @Jordan Unless you really mean `return` by the use of the word "returns", please replace it with "outputs" to put the discussions to rest…

Comment: @crashmstr I see what you mean now. I assumed that the intent *wasn't* to return a value. Heh. Confusing question!

Comment: @crashmstr correct my fault.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue when they were showing `console.log(dog.talk())`, then that shows an expectation of a return value. Changed now, but... terms do matter in this business to prevent this kind of confusion.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue The *question* doesn't need to be a word for word duplicate, the *issue and answers* should be. And the answers in the other question were fine IMO.

Comment: @deceze You're right, I just re-read the *answer* to that question. Laziness on my part...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined the "talk" property value as an arrow function, which means that the value of `this` in that function will be whatever the value of `this` was in the context of the function's definition. That's *not* the "dog" object, it's whatever `this` is where that `let` statement appears.

If you use a regular function instead, your code will work as you expect:

```
let dog = {
  s:'Woff',
  talk: function(){ console.log(this.s); }
};
console.log(dog.talk());
```

Now, on top of the `this` problem, your "talk" function doesn't return anything, so passing the results of a call to the function will always return `undefined`. (In the arrow function version, there <del>was</del> could have been a return value had it been a single-statement brace-free function body, but it would *also* have been `undefined` because `console.log()` doesn't return anything.) So:

```
let dog = {
  s:'Woff',
  talk: function(){ console.log(this.s); return this.s; }
};
console.log(dog.talk());
```

Now you'll see "Woff" from the `console.log()` in the function, and also from the outer `console.log()`.

Comment: Arrow functions with `{}` need a `return` statement. It’s only automatic when you use the single-statement version.

Comment: @JF They "need" a `return` statement *if and only if* you want to return something…